# How to deploy reports to SQL server 2008?

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services

I have reports as RDL files. I have to deploy them to SQL Server 2008. Please help me with step by step procedures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typical SSRS nomenclature for deploying reports is "publishing", so you might have better luck Googling that term.  Here is another resource to the MSDN page for it:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159270.aspx

This resource is for 2008 R2, but publishing of reports (at least from a procedural point of view) hasn't changed between 2008 and 2008 R2.

Answer (score 0):

You can find a tutorial detailing how to do this [here](http://alexduggleby.com/2008/07/18/sql-server-reporting-services-2008-tutorial-in-5-minutes-or-how-to-send-my-boss-a-report-from-a-view-quickly/).

It also happens to be the very first result that came up when I tried googling [deploy ssrs 2008](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=deploy%20ssrs%202008&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-GB%3aofficial&client=firefox-a).